# Control a particular line from a text file in java

Tags: java, file-io

I have written a function, but it has a problem. The function reads ID strings from a text file and should return `true`, when it matches an expected ID string value. If no match is found, it should return `false`.

However, the function always returns `false` even though I know the text file contains the expected ID. What am I doing wrong?

```
public boolean WriteOnTxt() throws IOException {
    boolean durum =false;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("HastaKayit.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    String[] parcala;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = br.readLine();
        parcala = line.split("#");

        if (parcala[0].equals(this.getPatientID())) {
            durum = true;
            break;
        } else {
            durum = false;  
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return durum;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Grunzwanzling   1#Michael#Jackson#02/02/1445 is the first string it splitting and  sends to parcala  and it takes a new object's id  then comparing each other if thats true function returns true else false

Comment: What's your problem then? Do you get wrong results?

Comment: Oh, you found an answer

Comment: program stops working at boolean durum =false; @Grunzwanzling

Comment: @Grunzwanzling an another problem :D

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working"? Does it crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're skipping lines:

`while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line = br.readLine();`

This section assigns a String to `line` twice so effectively only running your loop on every other line of data. To fix it, remove the second `line = br.readLine();`

Comment: @Maestus Please change to answered!